# Having an issue searching for a string in a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have tried to use a 'case' loop but it doesn't work for a reason unknown to me.

This is my script for the case loop.

```
echo "Do you wish to search again? [y/n]"
read INPUT_STRING2
case $INPUT_STRING2
   y)
   ;;
   *)
   exit
   ;;
```

Then I am having issues trying to make my script more user friendly, I want my script to tell the user if the string isn't found but I can't figure it out. I have tried using a case loop instead but have had no luck, and tried to use an else statement but it didn't work.

```
if grep -q $STRING $FILE ; then
             echo "string found"
fi
```

This part works but isn't all of what I want.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be an '`in`' missing in the line with the case statement as well as a closing `esac`:

```
echo "Do you wish to search again? [y/n]"
read INPUT_STRING2
case $INPUT_STRING2 in
   y)
   ;;
   *)
   exit
   ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

You did two syntax errors (`in` after the variable and `esac` as end of the case statement):

```
echo "Do you wish to search again? [y/n]"
read INPUT_STRING2
case $INPUT_STRING2 in
   "y")
   echo "Searching again"
   ;;
   *)
   exit
   ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want my script to tell the user if the string isn’t found ….   
>   I have tried ... to use an `else` statement but it didn't work.

What did you try?

```
if grep -q "$STRING" "$FILE"
then
        echo "string found"
else
        echo "string not found"
fi
```

works.

P.S. I advise you to quote all references to shell variables
(e.g., `"$INPUT_STRING2"`, `"$STRING"`, and `"$FILE"`)
unless you have a really good reason not to and you’re sure you know what you're doing. 
Conversely, you don't *need* to quote constant strings (e.g., `string found`)
unless they contain special characters. 
(Square brackets – “**`[`**” and “**`]`**” – are special characters in this context.) 
But it’s a good idea to quote them anyway.